# Building MariaDB 5.5.27 without OQGraph: How to deselect the plugin?

Tags: compiling, mysql, cmake

I'm trying to build [MariaDB 5.5.27](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/what-is-mariadb-55/) from source. In fact, I just need the client, but I seem to have to build the complete database system anyway.

While configuring with `cmake` and later compiling with `make`, I ran into the following problem:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:27:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base.hpp:36,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/property_map/vector_property_map.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:844,
                 from /home/bereziak/make/mariadb-5.5.27/storage/oqgraph/graphcore.cc:36:
/usr/include/boost/detail/sp_typeinfo.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::detail::sp_typeinfo boost::detail::sp_typeid_<boost::checked_array_deleter<unsigned char> >::ti_’:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_impl.hpp:149:75:   instantiated from ‘void* boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_pd<P, D>::get_deleter(const boost::detail::sp_typeinfo&) [with P = unsigned char*, D = boost::checked_array_deleter<unsigned char>]’
/home/bereziak/make/mariadb-5.5.27/storage/oqgraph/graphcore.cc:1101:1:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/detail/sp_typeinfo.hpp:77:48: error: conversion from ‘const char*’ to non-scalar type ‘boost::detail::sp_typeinfo’ requested
make[2]: *** [storage/oqgraph/CMakeFiles/oqgraph.dir/graphcore.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [storage/oqgraph/CMakeFiles/oqgraph.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Now, since I just need the client, I was thinking of deactivating the OQGraph plugin completely when configuring. But how should I do that? This is what I did:

```
cmake .
```

Inside my MariaDB directory, of course. How do I deactivate plugins/parts from it? with `configure` I'd simply use the option `--without-plugin_oqgraph`, I tried that with `cmake` as well, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [try with](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/source-configuration-options.html):

```
cmake . -DWITHOUT_OQGRAPH_STORAGE_ENGINE=1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally recommended to compile MariaDB Server yourself, there are many combinations of options and the build environment that can make things go wrong.

Indeed you can build without OQGRAPH, but even if you include it it's still a clean plugin so it won't be loaded at runtime unless you do say so. So if you just install the Boost and Boost graph dev packages on your system, the build will go fine without other tweaks.

Also do look at the build scripts the source packages provided.

Comment: As I said, I only need the client. However I have build many different databases myself, that's not the issue here. I just had problems using `cmake`.

Comment: Arjen, the build scripts do "cmake . -DWITHOUT_OQGRAPH=1 && make package" :) It is not too complicated, but OQGRAPH is complicated, because it does not compile even if boost was detected